# PROBLEMA AL MANDAR A IMPRESORA CON JAVA

Tags: java, impresora

Tengo un código en java y necesito imprimir tickets pero no imprime, detecta la impresora correcta y si envía el documento pero es como si se eliminara de la cola de impresión o no llegara a la impresora.

```
private void imprimirFolio(String folio) {
        System.out.println("Entra a imprimir");
        try {
            PrintService p = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            System.out.println(p.getName());

            DocPrintJob doc = p.createPrintJob();
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc d = null;

            String textoTicket = folio;

            d = new SimpleDoc(textoTicket.getBytes(), flavor, null);
            
            doc.print(d, null);

        } catch (PrintException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido imprimir el ticket.", "Awsys", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error general: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tenés la certeza de que sí se envía a la impresora?

Comment: Desconecté la impresora y ejecuté el método, y el documento aparece en cola, pero si está conectada no aparece

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de documente es, un PDF, un .doc, un .txt?

Comment: Es un String que recibe y es el texto que quiero imprimir

Comment: De la documentación, la recomendación es: *"Siempre consultar el servicio de impresión para determinar qué tipos de documento soporta"*; es decir, usa los parámetros de `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices()` primero para asegurarte que es la impresora deseada y si realmente soporta el tipo de documento que envías; de lo contrario la impresora podría interpretar equivocadamente lo que le mandas e imprimir nada; en el mundo de las impresoras (marcas, controladores, protocolos, tecnologías, capacidades, etc.) nada hay que "darlo por sentado".